how to open a pdf to specific page and zoom in python in mac-os
I am trying to open a pdf in mac-os to specific page and zoom programatically.
But I am unable to do so.
Here is my code, can somebody please let me know what I need to change?
import subprocess
import os
import traceback

def open_pdf_with_adobe(pdf_path, page_num, zoom):
    try:
        # Ensure the PDF path is absolute
        pdf_path = os.path.abspath(pdf_path)

        # Path to Adobe Acrobat Reader on macOS
        path_to_acrobat = "/Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader"

        # Construct the command
        command = [
            path_to_acrobat,
            pdf_path,
            "/A",
            f"page={page_num}&zoom={zoom}"
        ]

        # Execute the command
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.wait()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

# Example usage
pdf_path = "/Users/granth.jain/Desktop/Work/Wi-Fi CERTIFIED n Test Plan v2.21_0.pdf"
page_num = 12  # Adjust the page number as needed
zoom = 100   # Adjust the zoom level as needed

open_pdf_with_adobe(pdf_path, page_num, zoom)

correct pdf is opening, but it is not giving proper page num and zoom that I have specified.

Why you use Windows path syntax on macos ?

In which app do you want to open the PDF?

I want to open it in adobe acrobat.

import os

import subprocess

# Define the PDF path, page number, and zoom level
book = "YourBookTitle"  # Replace with your actual book title
page_num = 2  # Replace with your desired page number
zoom = 150  # Replace with your desired zoom level (in percentage)

path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(f'/path/to/Books/{book}.pdf')  # Replace with the actual path

# AppleScript to open the PDF in Preview and set the page and zoom
script = f"""
tell application "Preview"
    open POSIX file "{path_to_pdf}"
    delay 1
    set the bounds of the front window to {zoom}
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "g" using {{"command down", "shift down"}}
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "{page_num}"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
"""

# Run the AppleScript using osascript
process = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-e', script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if process.returncode == 0:
    print(f"Successfully opened {path_to_pdf} to page {page_num} at {zoom}% zoom")
else:
    print(f"Failed to open PDF: {stderr.decode('utf-8')}")


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

bounds of the front window is a rectangle, not a percentage. {{"command down", "shift down"}} doesn't work.
